# Ubuntu 16.04 and amdgpu issues

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics

So I upgraded from 15.10 and I used fglrx driver.

Now that has been deprecated and amdgpu driver is the new recommended one.

Unfortunately, since I upgraded my system just doesn't work anymore.

I can boot if I use the "nomodeset" option on the boot line but then graphics are pretty much useless.

I also tried "radeon.modeset=0"  but then again X crashes on boot.

If I give no options then the system just hangs right after grub screen.

Can anyone help me here? I really appreciate any help.

My system has 2 4k screens running off of a Radeon R7 370 graphics card, one is connected to the HDMI output and the other to the Display Port.

Thanks.

Comment: I found that running RX 480 Over a single display using AMDGPU-Pro Driver was possible. unfortunately we can blame AMD for not supporting their driver over Multiple displays in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you can do:
1) try a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, if you didn't do that(updating without wiping all data could cause problems)
2) try using the radeonsi driver instead of the amdgpu one (I read that the amdgpu one is mostly for newer AMD cards such as R9 380,285 etc)

I had similar problem with my AMD graphics card, I have dual monitor setup, and after install, only one monitor worked. After installing fglrx drivers, the system wouldn't come up. I had to install Ubuntu 14.04 and install fglrx drivers from the settings menu.

So if nothing works, maybe you'll have to downgrade back to 15.10.

Sorry I'm kind of new to Linux, but since noone else responded, I atleast tried to help you with what I know.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try the radeonsi driver maybe that works.

Comment: Radeonsi drivers did not work as well. I think I am downgrading to 15.10, which means I need to reinstall everything... kinda sux but whatever.

Comment: That's Linux, man. Not everything works 100%%. I have R9 380, which is quite a new card, but still when I upgraded to 16.04, audio didn't work through HDMI. Hopefully they will work more on the driver and we can all be happy then.

Comment: Audio through hdmi works fine, always has for me.. You go into sound settings & click on hdmi where it says "Play sound through"..

Answer (score 1):

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

So... You may not like this. I'm not sure what generation that card you have is... But if it's not basically brand new, you're gonna have a bad time. AMD has been working on an open source replacement for fglrx for a while now (and want everyone to use the open source one they just released, but this one only works with the newest generation of AMD cards), and with the release of an LTS Ubuntu, decided that they didn't want to support an older driver for 3 more years. Your choices (if that card is not the newest generation) are:

Stay on 15.10

Or

Use the horrible older AMD open source drivers (basically means you can't play games or do any sort of graphics work)

Or

Buy a newer AMD card.

I like these choices as much as you do, seeing as how I'm in the same situation. My next card will come from Nvidia.

Comment: I have a Radeon R9 270 X (Pitcairn) that works perfectly fine with the open-source drivers in 16.04. Granted, it doesn't support OpenCL, but graphics performance is acceptable.