# R7 265 Ubuntu 16.04 Amd Drivers

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics

I finished installing Ubuntu

My system runs on a low res (1024x768)

Trying to install proprietary amd drivers instead of Xorg crashes the program

Trying to install drivers from amd site fails and gets me into low res mode(640x480)

and then system wont boot in graphics mode

Also it R7 265 is recognised as HD 7850

Comment: Same graphics card here, installed incompatible stuck in login loop. Removing driver solved my problem.

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu now but I still have this odd resolution (1024x768) and I cant change it in settings

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems. LinuxMint 17.3 (Ubuntu 14.04) does well on my dual monitor configuration. That is, using the proprietary <kbd>fglrx</kbd> driver. I can get 1440x900 on both displays, even though one connection is VGA straight and the other VGA through a HDMI-to-VGA converter.

Using an AMD Radeon HD 6450 PCI_e graphics card and 2 Asus VE198S LED monitors, with 1440x900 as max resolution and VGA/DVI-D/HDMI ports.

Whatever I tried - running LinuxMint 18 with either KDE or Cinnamon as live distro from a USB stick - I could not get anything better than a disappointing 1024x768 resolution on both screens. So, I'll stick to Ubuntu 14.04 and <kbd>fglrx</kbd> as long as necessary (and possible).

[EDIT:] Maybe this information is helpful? > 
[Ubuntu 16.04 and amdgpu issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760769/ubuntu-16-04-and-amdgpu-issues)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but I'm gonna answer for the sake of community.

First of all, it's normal that your graphics card is detected as HD 7850. Here's a snippet of `lspci` command: `VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850 / R7 265 / R9 270 1024SP]`

I found a workaround to solve your issue, but first you need to uninstall the AMD drivers you installed. The solution is simply to add a custom resolution. I quoted the answer form another thread with some minor edits [How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

Use **cvt**
 Syntax is: cvt width height refreshrate

ex. `cvt 1680 1050 60`

this gives you:
`# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync`

Now tell this to **xrandr**:
`xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync`

Type `xrandr` This will show you some **info**. looks like this 
`Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25

   848x480       60.00

   640x480       59.94

DVI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1680x1050_60.00 (0x5d1) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz`

check the name of the connecting port in my case `DVI-0`

Then you can now add it to the table of possible resolutions of an output of your choice:
`xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1680x1050_60.00`

Finally, Open **Display settings** and choose the new resolution you just add

Edit: you will notice that all of this disappear after restart
Type in Terminal your last 2 commands at this form in this case: `echo "xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync; xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1680x1050_60.00" >> fix.sh` 
Search for "Startup Application" and browse the file you just created in command field, then hit OK.